# Ubuntu UWSGI Permission Denied

Tags: django, uwsgi, supervisord

I am doing the command :
`sudo supervisorctl update`
`sudo supervisorctl status`

This is the response i get from running the command

```
bridged                          RUNNING   pid 9808, uptime 0:01:57
celery                           RUNNING   pid 9809, uptime 0:01:57
site                             FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Here is my site.conf code, this site.conf is supposed to run under django environment, in my webEnv environment there is the uwsgi runner. The uwsgi is used as worker for online judge website.

```
[program:site]
command=/home/jeff/webEnv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
directory=/home/jeff/site
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile=/tmp/site.stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/site.stderr.log
```

So i try checking the site.stderr.log, and here what the response said about the code.

```
detected number of CPU cores: 3
current working directory: /home/jeff/site
writing pidfile to /tmp/dmoj-site.pid
open("/tmp/dmoj-site.pid"): Permission denied [core/utils.c line 3>[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.22 (64bit) on [Sun Jul 30 13:29:09 2023] ***compiled with version: 11.3.0 on 29 July 2023 17:26:29
os: Linux-5.19.0-50-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul>nodename: Ubuntu
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 3
current working directory: /home/jeff/site
writing pidfile to /tmp/dmoj-site.pid
open("/tmp/dmoj-site.pid"): Permission denied [core/utils.c line 3>
```

My uwsgi.ini code is like this.

```
[uwsgi]
# Socket and pid file location/permission.
uwsgi-socket = /tmp/dmoj-site.sock
chmod-socket = 666
pidfile = /tmp/dmoj-site.pid

# You should create an account dedicated to running dmoj under uws>#uid = dmoj-uwsgi
#gid = dmoj-uwsgi

# Paths.
chdir = /home/jeff/site
pythonpath = /home/jeff/site
virtualenv = /home/jeff/webEnv

# Details regarding DMOJ application.
protocol = uwsgi
master = true
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=dmoj.settings
module = dmoj.wsgi:application
optimize = 2

# Scaling settings. Tune as you like.
memory-report = true
cheaper-algo = backlog
cheaper = 3
cheaper-initial = 5
cheaper-step = 1
cheaper-rss-limit-soft = 201326592
cheaper-rss-limit-hard = 234881024
workers = 7
```

Is there any idea what's happening w my code?

I am trying to run supervisor and uwsgi.